# How can I eagerly fetch data on this query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to eagerly fetch `Action` and `Roles` on this NHibernate query

```
menuItems = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession
    .QueryOver<TopMenuItem>()
    .JoinAlias(i => i.Action, () => ua)
    .JoinAlias(() => ua.Roles, () => ro)
    .List();
```

I see that query is returning all necessary data trough inner joins but when later I access `Roles`, a new query is executed to fetch the collection.

OTOH, this query works perfect but I'd like to avoid using HQL

```
menuItems = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession
    .CreateQuery(@"
        from TopMenuItem i 
        join fetch i.Action a
        join fetch a.Roles"
    )
    .List<TopMenuItem>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join's need to be LeftOuterJoins to be eagerly loaded properly.

```
menuItems = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession
.QueryOver<TopMenuItem>()
.JoinAlias(i => i.Action, () => ua, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.JoinAlias(() => ua.Roles, () => ro, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.List();
```

Comment: Indeed this work thanks. Do you have any reference why this needs to be like this?

Comment: @Claudio, I don't remember the source.  I had the same question a while back and found a document somewhere, I think it was one of Ayende's blog entries, that explained why.  I understood it when I read it, but have since forgotten the reason.